# Concatenate DSL chunks in Groovy for Jenkinsfile

Tags: data-structures, groovy, closures, concatenation, jenkins-groovy

I want to reach the following with loop :

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Run Tests') {
            parallel {
                stage('Test On Windows') {
                    agent {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh "run-tests.bat"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Test On Linux') {
                    agent {
                        label "linux"
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh "run-tests.sh"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried :

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Run Tests') {
          script {
            parallel generatedStages()
        }
    }
}


def generateStages() {
  return ["windows", "linux"].collect{ generateOneStage(it)}
}

def generateOneStage(os) {
  return {
            stage("Test On ${os}") {
                agent {
                    label "${os}"
                }
                steps {
                    sh os ? "run-tests.bat" : "run-tests.sh"
                }
                post {
                    always {
                        junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                    }
                }
            }
   }
}
```

The problem is that `generateStages` does not generate a closure ( `{ stage(){}  stage(){} }`). Instead, it generates an array `[{stage(){}}, {stage(){}}]`

Is there a way in groovy to concatenate these blocks and get a closure (as before making it dynamic ) instead of a getting an array ?

Indeed,  Jenkins throws this error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got
>   [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@7ff95c2e,
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@2b80a3bb ]     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.singleParam(DSL.java:598)
>
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:586)

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ?